# generate an app.cache with Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, sprockets, cache-manifest

We have a site that builds locally with Jekyll and Jekyll-Assets (which uses sprockets).

We'd like to be able to generate a cache manifest that has all the files that go into the resultant site. We'd like to generate this as a part of the build process so that the entire site will be available offline. (It's a very small site, but we're opposed to manual work!)

The images and the css have a hash appended to the filename during the build so we can't predict the outcome.

We've tried using the `{% asset_path logo.png %}` etc. method, but it doesn't get processed. I.e. it leaves the Liquid tag as is in the final file. ERB *does* work (`<%= 2+3 %>` gives 5) but we can't see a way of accessing the resultant files.

We are considering another task runner to wrap the whole thing, but this feels like overkill.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your page with the liquid that didn't work?

Answer (score 7):

[`jekyll-perf`](https://github.com/ebello/jekyll-perf) builds a `manifest.appcache` file. The project appears as if it might be dormant, but they were doing it as follows. Hopefully this is useful as a starting point. You may need to adjust things for your asset paths etc., naturally.

(I'm not sure if the `for` stuff in this will take care of your appended hash issue or not. Apologies if this is exactly what you've already tried and it hasn't worked for you.)

```
---
---
CACHE MANIFEST

# rev {{ site.buildtime }}

CACHE:
{% asset_path all.css %}
{% for page in site.pages %}{% if page.url != '/manifest.appcache' %}{{ page.url }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for item in site.images %}{{ item.url }}
{% endfor %}
{% for item in site.scripts %}{{ item.url }}
{% endfor %}

NETWORK:
*
http://*
https://*
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget :

- The empty front matter in your manifest

  ```
  ---
  # empty front matter
  ---
  [...]
  ```
- To loop over your collections if your outputting them.